# Linear independent vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I have this problem and need your help :
$V_1$,  $V_2$, $V_3$ are linearly independent vectors.

And $W_1 = 2 V_1 + V_2\ ;\   W_2 = V_1 -2V_2 + V_3\ ;\ W_3 = V_3 -3V_2$

Are those three vectors also linearly independent ? 
I thought about using the determinant to find out but it is way too long, 
Does anyone have an easier way ? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: When $v_1,\cdots,v_m$ are linearly independent, the family of vectors $w_1,\cdots,w_m$, defined as $w_j=\alpha_j^1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_j^mv_m$, is linearly independen if and only if $\det((a^i_j)_{i,j\le m})\ne 0$. The person who gave you the assignment probably does not deem the calculation of a $3\times 3$ determinant with small integer entries and a lot of zeros "way too long". My personal opinion is that said person is 100% right, because the calculation of an explicit $3\times 3$ (or "*even*" $4\times4$) determinant should not pose a challenge to an accomplished student of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can think about it:

Take $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $c_1W_1 + c_2W_2 + c_3W_3 = 0.$

Now check whether all $c_i's$ $(i = 1, 2, 3)$ are zero or not. If all $c_i's$ are zero then three vectors are linearly independent otherwise dependent.

Comment: C's ? Sorry I'm confused,  should I derive ?

Comment: yes you have to derive. Put the value of $W_i$ and $V_i$'s are linearly independent. Use this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the given equalities as a system of linear equations with unknown $v_1, v_2, v_3.$ Then $w_1,w_2,w_3$ is linear independent iff determinant of system is non-zerow.